Google API for Maps Gecode Function not returning results for a specific zip code
I am posting to the geocode API and for a certain zip code (11707) it returns zero results. I know this is a valid zip.  Also with other zips the same post works fine.
The non-working call is:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=11707&key= (i put my key here)
The working call is:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=11950&key= (I put my key here)
Any idea how I can get this resolved?
I was expecting the Geocode API to return the geocoded information for this zip code.

This is an expected behavior for Geocoding when only the postal code is provided as input, as detailed in https://issuetracker.google.com/73030863 and https://issuetracker.google.com/75985322, because a 4-digit or 5-digit number can often represent multiple locations(ambiguous query), even within a single country.
As a workaround, consider using Component Filtering and/or Region Biasing to narrow down your results.
This request with component filtering (postal_code & country) returned results: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|postal_code:11707&key=YOUR_API_KEY
